# Running mysqldump from a PHP script doesn't work but works on SSH

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to back a database via a PHP script using this one simple line:

```
passthru("/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=localhost --user=\"myuser\" --password=\"mypass\" db_name > /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/tools/dbbackup-2011-12-17.sql");
```

I get no errors or warnings or anything. but if I copy that string and execute it exactly as is on the server via SSH it works perfectly.

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=localhost --user="myuser" --password="mypass" db_name > /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/tools/dbbackup-2011-12-17.sql
```

I tried using exec() and system() instead of passthru() but same results. This is really strange and I can't focure out what could be the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs and the syslog? This is usually found in /var/log/apache2/ and /var/log/syslog and might say what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### An educated guess

If I can make an educated guess it's because the user that runs the php-script (ie. user the httpd is run as) doesn't have permission to write to `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/tools/`.

Though the user you are using to execute the command has.

---

### `STDERR` and `STDOUT`

To see if there is anything printed to `STDERR` that is relevant to the problem, use the below snippet!

```
$tubes = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),
  // print contents on STDOUT to file
  1 => array("file", "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/tools/dbbackup-2011-12-17.sql", "w"),
  2 => array("pipe", "w")
);

$p_handle = proc_open (
  "/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=localhost --user=\"myuser\" --password=\"mypass\" db_name",
  $tubes, $pipes
);

if (is_resource ($p_handle)) {
    fclose ($pipes[0]);

    $stderr_data = stream_get_contents ($pipes[2]); fclose($pipes[2]);

    $proc_ret    = proc_close ($p_handle);

    echo "--------- STDERR:\n$stderr_data\n";
    echo "------------ RET: $proc_ret\n";
} else {
  die ("Unable to execute external resource, aborting!");
}
```

---

### Check the log files!

Have you checked the `error_log` associated with your `httpd`?

Comment: that's a reasonable explanation. how would i execute the script as a different user? I'm currently logged in as 'root' on ssh.

Comment: @bruno  Well, you definitely don't want to run the httpd as root.. instead [`chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)/[`chown`](http://ss64.com/bash/chown.html) the directory to grant write access to the user used by your httpd.

Comment: thanks. i tried just changing the folder permissions to 777 just for testing and still having the same problem.

Comment: thanks. The script didn't output anything but it's definitely a permissions issue with the PHP user running the script compared to the root user that I ran as on SSH. Looking into that now. Thanks.

Comment: @bruno I added a `die` which prints information if php was unable to create the process in the snippet.