# mysqldump with php and exec results in an empty file

Tags: php, mysql, exec

System is Mac 10.12.1, PHP 7, mysql 5.7.16

Here is my code:

```
 $cmd ="mysqldump --opt --host=".$this->dbHost." --user=".$this->user." --
 password=".$this->password." ".$this->dbName." > ".$this->sqlFile;
 echo exec($cmd, $output);
 var_dump($output);
 var_dump($cmd);
```

Results are:
2016-11-05-02:55:05
/Users/user/Google_Drive/Repositories/deploy/includes/Database.class.php:70:
array (size=0)
  empty
/Users/user/Google_Drive/Repositories/deploy/includes/Database.class.php:71:string 'mysqldump --optd  -uroot -proot sandbox > /Users/user/Google_Drive/Backups/sandbox/2016-11-05-02-55-05.sql' (length=112)

The folder "sandbox" I've run sudo chmod -R 777 sandbox

```
Terminal run in : /Users/user/Google_Drive/Backups/
ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxrwx   4 _www     staff   136  4 Nov 11:34 .
drwxrwxrwx@ 16 user     staff   544  4 Nov 11:37 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 user     staff  6148  4 Nov 18:37 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwx   6 _www     staff   204  4 Nov 19:55 sandbox

Terminal run in : /Users/user/Google_Drive/Backups/sandbox

ls -al
total 96
drwxrwxrwx  6 _www     staff    204  4 Nov 19:55 .
drwxrwxrwx  4 _www     staff    136  4 Nov 11:34 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user     staff  49152  4 Nov 18:46 2016-11-05-01-45-58.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 _www     staff      0  4 Nov 18:47 2016-11-05-01-47-22.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 _www     staff      0  4 Nov 19:54 2016-11-05-02-54-37.sql
-rw-r--r--  1 _www     staff      0  4 Nov 19:55 2016-11-05-02-55-05.sql
```

When I run the command via terminal the file is created correctly.

```
mysqldump --optd  -uroot -proot sandbox > /Users/user/Google_Drive/Backups/sandbox/2016-11-05-02-55-05.sql
```

Note: I've tried several variations of mysqldump and think it is a permission issue.

Comment: so why use PHP for this at all??

Comment: The commands are dynamically generated - and part of a migration script.  I'd sooner not use bash for it.  I'm only showing the part of the code that is causing an issue

Comment: Use `shell_exec` instead of `exec` to get the output.

Comment: Or even better, use proc_open and set the output stream to the file writer stream.

Comment: proc_write worked!! Thank you - I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547257/running-mysqldump-from-a-php-script-doesnt-work-but-works-on-ssh - which gave me a useful error and needed to add the full location for mysqldump but on terminal I do not need it.